# ASP.NET web forms- custom error page for 404 error is working only when asking .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-error-pages

I added a custom error page to handle 404 errors.

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

The problem is that this works only when I try to access a .aspx page like

```
localhost/abcd.aspx
```

where abcd.aspx is not a real page in the app.
however, when I try to access just `localhost/abcd` it throws me the default IIS error page and not the custom page I made.
How can I config my custom error page to catch all 404 errors?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701794/4180382

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom error, use the following syntax in CMD run this:

> **appcmd set config /section:httpError** **/+"[statusCode=**'int'**,subStatusCode=**'int'**,prefixLanguageFilePath=**'string'**,path=**'string'**,response**

Explanation:

> The variable **statusCode** int is the HTTP status code. The variable **subStatusCode** int is the HTTP sub status code. The variable **prefixLanguageFilePath** string is the path of the prefix language file. The variable **path** string is the **path** of the custom error file.
>
> For example, to add a custom error for any 401.2 errors returned from the server, type the following at the command prompt, and then press Enter:
>
> **appcmd set config /section:httpErrors /+"[statusCode='401',subStatusCode='2',prefixLanguageFilePath='%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr',path='401.htm',ResponseMode='File']"**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753103(v=ws.10)#command-line